# can't copy pointer's address to h_addr_list

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dns, network-programming

I'm having some difficulties with coping the dns server's answare to a Host-Address Query, to the h_addr_list field at the `struct hostent`.

The function I describe, works fine for hosts that has no alias names, I debuged it and it works just fine. 
However, for a host name with alias, when I debug the program, I see it won't copy the pointer of the IPv4 address at the answer buffer from the dns-server, to the struct I created, and leave it with a `Bad-Pointer` field.

the IPv4 printing function goes like this:

```
const int numOfAns=ntohs(dns->ans_count);
struct hostent remoteHost;
int numOfIP=0;
char **addressList;
addressList = new char*[numOfAns];
remoteHost.h_addr_list = addressList;
for(i=0;i<numOfAns;i++) {
    if(ntohs(answers[i].resource->type) == 1) { //IPv4 address
        numOfIP++;
        remoteHost.h_addr_list[i] = (char*)answers[i].rdata;
    }
}
remoteHost.h_addr_list[numOfIP] = NULL;
return &remoteHost;
```

Comment: Not sure if it is correct in your case, but you're not copying the char array, your copying the pointer to the char array. If answers go away, you're left with dangling pointers.

Comment: `remoteHost` seems to be declared locally, do not return a reference to it to the calling function as `remoteHost` will be invalided on this function return.

Comment: I think this isn't the problem since this function works for every host that has **no** alias name

Comment: How having or not having an alias name differ in your code?

Comment: The indexing `remoteHost.h_addr_list[numOfIP]` might very well overwrite something put there by `remoteHost.h_addr_list[i] =`, which is most likely incorrect.